# How can I view diff between two revisions of a file in Google Drive

Tags: google-drive-api

Is this possible with Google Drive APIs?

Comment: By "diff', do you mean the individual revisions, or the *nix diff(1) of 2 files? Yes to the former, no to the latter.

Comment: Ok, so I will not be able to find just the delta between the revisions.

Comment: is there any paid plugin / utility which can be used in conjunction with the APIs? Or any enhancement in similar lines are in roadmap of Google Drive APIs?

Comment: Did you ever find a way to get the delta between two files?

Comment: It looks like it's natively supported http://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/5820

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can see the different revisions of a file with the [revisions.list()](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/revisions/list) method. You can retrieve a specific revision with [revisions.get()](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/revisions/get).